# Simple, jquery .hover not working

Tags: jquery

I'm really sorry to ask this but I've tried everything (that I know of and understand) and can't get this to work.

```
$("nav > ul > li").hover(function () {
    var underground = $(this).attr('title');
    $("#womble").html(underground);
},function () {
    $("#womble").html(overground);
});
```

This is in an external script file that is called after Jquery1.7.2 is called.
I am loath to put it in a function and call it via the HTML DOM onmouseover event handler.

Is it that I can't define the variable from `$(this)` like that, within the `function(){}`?
Or is this right, and it's just not triggering for some other reason?

The variable "overground" is globally defined elsewhere.
And yes the html `<li>` tags have `"title="` and not `"Title="` - so I've checked for that, as well... I'm sure that it is something simple and obvious. So many apologies again for my ignorance and/or stupidity.

The HTML is:

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li title="Wombling free"><a></a></li>
<li title="the wombles of"><a></a></li>
<li title="Wimbledon Common"></li>
<li title="are we"></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Thank you all, I had tried putting the code in the $(document).ready function a dozen times, but now it works! ... Much appreciated for all the suggestions. I guess I don't understand the event handlers that well, as I had thought that that wouldn't make any difference. I had thought that the code would only be triggered by the hover event. But clearly it has to be in the document.ready so that jquery can register it somehow with the relevant element. Though I had tried the putting the code in the document ready function.

It's working now and actually I've no idea what the difference/mistake between what I was trying before and now! 
I have stuck it all in a function and put it in the document.ready function. I must have had a minor syntax error at the end of my document. ready section, or something as I had tried putting the code in directly before a dozen times. Thanks everyone for your incredibly rapid responses. And if you don't know what a womble is, it was a children's programme about talking bears that picked up litter on Wimbledon Common from the 1970s. Yes, I'm that old; probably why I'm so dim.

Comment: It looks ok. What is nav? is that a class or an ID?

Comment: [This all looks fine for me in a simple test case](http://jsfiddle.net/jCfKx/) @PaulRadich That's an HTML5 Element.

Comment: $("nav > ul > li") - is this correct selector? Don't you have anything between tags? Try with $("nav ul li").

Comment: Paul, thanks. I'm guessing my mistake is elsewhere then.

Comment: You have to provide the HTML code to see if the `$("nav > ul > li")` is correct.

Comment: What goes wrong? Do you get JS errors? Maybe jQuery hasn't yet loaded when your code is executed?

Comment: Zenith, sorry, I added the edit about the overground variable after you helpfully commented.

Comment: Are you sure the `nav`, `ul`, and `li` elements are defined when your code is run? If you say your code is in a “file that is called after Jquery1.7.2 is called”, this might be in the `<head>` before any content is defined. If that is the case, wrap your code in a document-ready event handler.

Comment: marlenunez. The nav code is fine, I'm sure, but thanks. It's just standard opening and closing tags and renders fine.

Comment: Based on what you have provided your selector is wrong. Perhaps you could add a bit more of an example of the HTML so we could validate the selector is correct?

Comment: Raphael, thanks, I had tried that, and forgot to mention it.

Comment: showdev, just nothing happens. There must be a conflict with some of my other code.

Comment: “Nothing” is exactly what would happen if you forgot to wrap it in `$(document).ready(function() {…});`.

Comment: Pete, tried that, it doesn't seem to make any difference. Can a hover function be fired before the page is ready anyway?

Comment: LukLed Tried with the > between the tags too. Thanks though.... :-(

Comment: Modified @Ohgodwhy's fiddle and it works fine: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jCfKx/1/)

Comment: Have you tried looking at it through a debugger? (in Chrome: ctrl + shift + j) I'd also try putting in some alerts to see if you're actually calling the script properly, and if your hover event is getting triggered

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, but there would not be 15+ comments if you would have provided all the relevant info in your question. Check Jon Skeet's post on [how to ask a good SO question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert these lines in the external script file:

```
console.log($("nav > ul > li").length); // should log a number > 0
console.log($("#womble").length);       // should log a number > 0
console.log(overground);                // should log a defined value
// just before the problem function
$("nav > ul > li").hover(function () {
    var underground = $(this).attr('title');
    $("#womble").html(underground);
},function () {
    $("#womble").html(overground);
});
```

Check the browser console. Is the output what is expected?

Comment: This isn't the answer but it was an error in the document.ready section I think. Thank you all.

Comment: @Max: I just want to confirm that the code is working now. Is the problem resolved?

Answer (score -1):

If the jQuery script is called *before* calling the HTML through AJAX, then the HTML would not exist in the page when jQuery tries to hook the events.

Instead, simply call the jQuery script after AJAX loaded the page. Through you do not specify if you are using AJAX, I faced the same issue and used this very same method to solve it.

Comment: @LawrenceAiello This is, in fact, an answer to the question.